# llvmlite AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'LLVMPY_AddSymbol'

Tags: python, llvmlite

I want to use llvmlite in an Android Studio project with chaquopy. I built the requiered wheel, but i get this error when running the app:

```
Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'LLVMPY_AddSymbol'
          at <python>.llvmlite.binding.ffi.__getattr__(ffi.py:138)
          at <python>.llvmlite.binding.dylib.<module>(dylib.py:36)
          at <python>.java.chaquopy.import_override(import.pxi:26)
```

the function in ffi.py where the error originates from:

```
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self._fntab[name]
        except KeyError:
            # Lazily wraps new functions as they are requested
            cfn = getattr(self._lib, name)
            wrapped = _lib_fn_wrapper(self._lock, cfn)
            self._fntab[name] = wrapped
            return wrapped
```